# 403 forbidden error on while accessing google task api

Tags: java, android, http-status-code-403, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I am trying to sync with google tasks. I got the tasks list from default list. Now I want to insert a task in default list.

I followed the documentation for this.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/insert

Also I have set the task api as enabled. I have generate the client id also.

OAuth 2.0 client IDs

Name Creation date Type Client ID

Android client 1 Mar 19, 2016 Android 256433535354-h653umd5mddo5t139moof3cvd56asnec.apps.googleusercontent.com

Still when I try to insert a task I get the error that of 403 forbidden and the error message is: insufficient permission.

I have also set OAuth 2.0 scopes as manage all your task. From here:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/tasks/v1/

Still I am unable to insert the task.

I am not getting what's going wrong.. Please help..

Dependencies:

```
   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev41-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    private TextView mOutputText;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
    static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
    private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
    private static final String[] SCOPES = { TasksScopes.TASKS_READONLY };
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<String> result1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams tlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        mOutputText = new TextView(this);
        mOutputText.setLayoutParams(tlp);
        mOutputText.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        mOutputText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mOutputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        activityLayout.addView(mOutputText);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Tasks API ...");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        setContentView(activityLayout);

        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
    }


    /**
     * Called whenever this activity is pushed to the foreground, such as after
     * a call to onCreate().
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            refreshResults();
        } else {
            mOutputText.setText("Google Play Services required: " +
                    "after installing, close and relaunch this app.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
     * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
     * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
     *     activity result.
     * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
     *     activity result.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(
            int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                        data.getExtras() != null) {
                    String accountName =
                            data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    if (accountName != null) {
                        mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    mOutputText.setText("Account unspecified.");
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    chooseAccount();
                }
                break;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to get a set of data from the Google Tasks API to display. If the
     * email address isn't known yet, then call chooseAccount() method so the
     * user can pick an account.
     */
    private void refreshResults() {
        if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
            chooseAccount();
        } else {
            if (isDeviceOnline()) {
                new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("No network connection available.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts an activity in Google Play Services so the user can pick an
     * account.
     */
    private void chooseAccount() {
        startActivityForResult(
                mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
     * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date. Will
     * launch an error dialog for the user to update Google Play Services if
     * possible.
     * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
     *     date on this device; false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        final int connectionStatusCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
            showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
            return false;
        } else if (connectionStatusCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
     * or out of date.
     * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
     *     Google Play Services on this device.
     */
    void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
            final int connectionStatusCode) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                connectionStatusCode,
                MainActivity.this,
                REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        dialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * An asynchronous task that handles the Google Tasks API call.
     * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
     */
    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks mService = null;
        private Exception mLastError = null;

        public MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            mService = new com.google.api.services.tasks.Tasks.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Tasks API Android Quickstart")
                    .build();
        }

        /**
         * Background task to call Google Tasks API.
         * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
         */
        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //getTasks();
                insertTask();
                return getTasks();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Fetch a list of the first 10 task lists.
         * @return List of Strings describing task lists, or an empty list if
         *         there are no task lists found.
         * @throws IOException
         */

        private List<String> getTasks() throws IOException{
            List<String> result1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            List<Task> tasks =
                    mService.tasks().list("@default").setFields("items/title").execute().getItems();
            if (tasks != null) {
                for (Task task : tasks) {
                    result1.add(task.getTitle());
                }
            } else {
                result1.add("No tasks.");
            }

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result1);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return result1;
        }


        private void insertTask() throws IOException
        {

            Task task = new Task();
            task.setTitle("New Task");
            task.setNotes("Please complete me");

            Task result = mService.tasks().insert("@default", task).execute();
            System.out.println(result.getTitle());

        }

        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {
            // List up to 10 task lists.
            List<String> taskListInfo = new ArrayList<String>();
            TaskLists result = mService.tasklists().list()
                    .setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(10))
                    .execute();

            List<TaskList> tasklists = result.getItems();


            if (tasklists != null) {
                for (TaskList tasklist : tasklists) {

                    taskListInfo.add(String.format("%s (%s)\n",
                            tasklist.getTitle(),
                            tasklist.getId()));
                }
            }


            return taskListInfo;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
                mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
                output.add(0, "Data retrieved using the Google Tasks API:");
                mOutputText.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", output));



            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (mLastError != null) {
                if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                    showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                            ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                    .getConnectionStatusCode());
                } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                    startActivityForResult(
                            ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                            MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } else {
                    mOutputText.setText("The following error occurred:\n"
                            + mLastError.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                mOutputText.setText("Request cancelled.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank u..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SCOPES` has a value `TASKS_READONLY`, you really won't be able to insert anything with that kind of scope. Change it to `TASKS` or other constants available (which is supposed to be the read/write access). More information about the the Authorization can be found in the [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/auth) page of the Tasks API documentation.

If you want to check out an Android Tasks sample, you can follow the instructions from their [Google API samples page](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html)